# Can't import a function from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a hard time importing my router file to the main project file.

Previously I just required dependencies separately and exported router variable and then I required my file and it was fine. But I want to use dependencies defined in the main file, so I've got something like this:

```
//router file
module.exports = function(router, request, f, moment, io) {
//blah
}

//server file
//all dependencies properly required

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index')(express.Router(), request, f, moment, io); //doesn't work
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

Comment: Just curious, why you import common resources (like request, moment, express-router etc.) vs just having the 'require('xx')` inside your router file?

Comment: I need the same dependency (socket.io) in multiple files and the rest is just so it's all in one place. It requires less writing and should give the same result.

Comment: Do you get errors or does it just not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work I just needed to return router in router file.

router.js

```
module.exports = function(router, request, f, moment, io) {
  //routes
  return router; //returning router at the end of a function
}
```

server.js

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/index')(express.Router(), request, f, moment, io)); //works
```